# segmentation fault in insertion into ternary search tree

Tags: c, search, data-structures, segmentation-fault, ternary-search-tree

i am trying to insert the charachter in to ternary search tree, please help me out with this segmentation fault ??
here is what i am doing to inser in to trie,on running this i am getting segmentation fault(core dumped )
 please help me out why this is so ??

```
int main(int argc ,char* agrv[])
{
TSTNode *root;
char *str;
cin >> str;
InsertTST(root,str);
DisplayTST(root);
return 0; 
}

TSTNode* InsertTST(TSTNode *root, char *str)
{
if(root== NULL){
    TSTNode *root = (TSTNode *)malloc(sizeof(TSTNode *));
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    root->eq = NULL;
    root->is_end_of_str = 0;

    return root;
}


if(root->data < *str)
    InsertTST(root->right, str);
else if (root->data == *str){
    if(*(str+1) != '\0')
    InsertTST(root->eq, str+1);
    else 
    root->is_end_of_str = 1;
}
else 
    InsertTST(root->left, str);

return root;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str;
cin >> str;
```

no allocation of memory, followed by a write to said memory = seg fault.